# Rotate through Array every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a simple rainbow clock, the idea is that every second that passes the background colors of the stripes change to the next color in the array. I'm trying to get the value of seconds to offset the array and then wrap around to the beginning.

for example:

```
var seconds = 0;

var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink'];
```

would become, when I iterate:

```
var seconds = 1;

var colors = ['pink', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet'];
```

I'm currently using this:

```
$('.color').each(function setColors(i) {
  $(this).css('background', colors[i]);
});
```

But I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var seconds = time.getSeconds();

$('.color').each(function setColors(i) {
  $(this).css('background', colors[i + seconds]);
});
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kathrynm/3sbng7zx/)

Thank you in advance for any help you may have :)

- K

Comment: I see you have the setTimeout for changing the seconds, but I don't see you attempting to change the colors any where in there.

Comment: I had SetTimeout for the setColors function but it was breaking it

Comment: Hint: (anyPositiveNumber % array.length) == range of [0, array length - 1]

Comment: you should not use setInterval, instead use set timeout read about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *pop* a color from the end of the array and *add* it to the start of the array using:

```
colors.unshift(colors.pop());
```

See demo below:

```js
// get seconds
setInterval(getSeconds, 1000);

// set colors
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink'];

// initalize colors
  $('.color').each(function setColors(i) {
    $(this).css('background', colors[i]);
  });

function getSeconds() {
  var time = new Date($.now());
  var seconds = time.getSeconds();
  $('#seconds').text(seconds);

  $('.color').each(function setColors(i) {
    $(this).css('background', colors[i]);
  });
  
  // shift the colors
  colors.unshift(colors.pop());
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#seconds {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 100;
}
.color {
  position: relative;
  height: 12.5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #456;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="seconds">seconds</div>

<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
<div class="color"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to alter the original array.  Just use modulus

```
function changeColors (start) {
    $('.color').each(function setColors(i) {
        $(this).css('background', colors[(i + start) % colors.length]);
    });
}
```

Call it with 0 on start, and call it in the loop giving it the seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
// get seconds

setInterval(getSeconds, 1000);

function getSeconds() {
  var time = new Date($.now());
  var seconds = time.getSeconds();
  $('#seconds').text(seconds);
  mutateArray();
  setColor();
};

// set colors

var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink'];

function setColor() {
    $('.color').each(function setColors(i) {
        $(this).css('background', colors[i]);
    });
}

function mutateArray() {
    var element = colors[colors.length-1];
    colors.splice(colors.length-1, 1);
    colors.splice(0, 0, element);
  console.log(colors);
};
```

Does something like this works for you?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, I'm researching mutating now. Thank you so much @md asiful haque :)